# Comments Plugin height bug

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-comments

Despite being pretty against implementing plugins onto my sites, I have decided to use the Comments Plugin on one of my pages. The plugin works fine, however, there seems to be a bug whereby the height of the iframe does not change in certain circumstances.

1. If I add a comment and then remove it, the height does not resize back down to fit the content tightly.
2. Occasionally, I load the page and the iframe is huge. This is rare and I find it very hard to recreate so I am not actually sure what the cause is but anyway.
3. There seems to be unpredictable padding at the bottom of the iframe.

I am aware that this is a problem with the plugin, not with my code but I just wanted to know if anyone else had experienced it and if they knew of a fix?

**What is the fastest and best way of implementing the plugin? i.e. FBML or iframe?**

*I have reported the aforementioned bug to Facebook and they have recognized that it does exist and claim that it is being looked into. However, this was over 2-3 months ago so I am not holding my breath*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a bug, then it's a bug (and to get facebook to admit to bugs is not easy).  So I'd say hang tight until they fix it.  I really don't think there's much you can do about it ...

...other than remove it from the DOM and re-add it to the DOM when it does break.

Or give the website user a "fix it" button that fires off the js to remove it from the DOM and re-add it back.

Comment: Hadn't thought of creating an autofix but irritatingly there would be no way to detect if it has gone wrong and I do not want to give my visitors the control to reload it. I will hang on with FB and hopefully they will get back to me. The site doesnt go live until September so they still have some time. :-)